# Apache PHP not working after Update

Tags: upgrade, apache2, php

Im using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

There was an Ubuntu-Update yesterday and after starting the pc today my apache php isnt working anymore. I get the download of the php-files instead of the website.

I tried to enable php again with

```
sudo a2enmod php5
```

But its not working.

I also tried to reinstall it.. But Im getting this error:

```
sudo apt-get purge libapache2-mod-php5
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen... Fertig
Einige Pakete konnten nicht installiert werden. Das kann bedeuten, dass
Sie eine unmögliche Situation angefordert haben oder, wenn Sie die
Unstable-Distribution verwenden, dass einige erforderliche Pakete noch
nicht erstellt wurden oder Incoming noch nicht verlassen haben.
Die folgenden Informationen helfen Ihnen vielleicht, die Situation zu lösen:

Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 libapache2-mod-php5 : Hängt ab von: libxml2 (>= 2.8.0) aber 2.7.8.dfsg-5.1ubuntu4.5 soll installiert werden
                       Empfiehlt: php5-cli soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete.
```

Comment: I don't really know Deutsch, but it says right there in the output it needs libxml2 version greater than the one it has so php-cli won't be installed. I can't really tell what "zurückgehaltene" is, it may be a "held" packet. There are answers on [clearing a wrongly held packet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages).

Answer (score 1):

Try to get `libxml2` >= 2.8.0

from: [“libxml2” 2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4.3 source package in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libxml2/2.9.0+dfsg1-4ubuntu4.3#yui_3_10_2_1_1375308673155_54)

Download it as `DEB` file, and double-click to install it (the faster way) .